# Storyboard not updating its design in latest version of xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am working on a project in Xcode and I made few changes to my storyboard design (mostly the font style and placeholder text and the text on the buttons). It shows the changes in the storyboard but when I run and build the project to the simulator, it still shows the old design and doesn't show the updated storyboard designs. I tried quitting Xcode and also did restart my MacBook but it still doesn't show the updated designs when I run it in simulator. Is there anything I missed or did wrong ? I am working on the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: Are you sure your project isn't loading from another interface file?

Comment: You need to quit Xcode and clean out all the caches, including the simulators. Follow _all_ the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073

Comment: I did the cleaning process but the problem is still there. I guess its the problem with the localization. I had 3 localisable.strings file which are "Localizable.strings(Base)"​, "Localizable.strings(English)" and "Localizable.strings(Norwegian)". 
How do I change my default build settings to build using the "Localizable.strings(Base)" file ? I tried deleting the other two files as I don't need them anymore but the problem is still there. I guess I need to remove the unwanted localizable.strings files and use only the "Localizable.strings(Base)" file as default. But how do I do that ?